# Error trying to set up a self signed certificate

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl, ipython, anaconda

I am in an EC2 instance trying to set up a notebook server to allow me to create an ipython notebook locally that runs on the EC2 instance. ([Following these instructions](http://randyzwitch.com/ipython-notebook-amazon-ec2/)).

When I try to create a self signed certificate using this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

I get the following message:

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/ssl/openssl.cnf
Unable to load config info from /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

I used the same process in a previous EC2 instance and it worked fine. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to be know bug: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/137

Answer (score 7):

Turns out this was a known bug with Anaconda. Details here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/228

Quick fix is to enter on the command line:

```
conda update openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your permissions for said config file?

```
ls -la /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/ssl/
```

If you don't have read permissions, you need to add them

```
sudo chmod +r /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Or simply try running the same command as root by preceding it with `sudo`

Comment: It is a non-existent path that the application was looking for. Turns out this was an anaconda bug - I posted the fix in an answer below